# Sync Google Email Accounts with Outlook

Tags: sync, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have multiple google email accounts (not just GMail, but ones set up with Google to handle email for other domains). All of these accounts sync with my Windows Phone, and I was wondering if its possible to extend the sync partnership to Outlook 2010 (maintain read/unread status, deleted, folders, etc). I have no interest in spending money on these accounts, so I was wondering if its possible to do it for free or with specific tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your phone is making a connection to each accounts... so must your desktop client (outlook)  Your phone isn't tying them together... it simply displays them on one screen.  Yes, you can setup as many accounts in outlook as your phone does (probably more).  Anything your phone can connect to... more than likely... outlook can as well.

Also, As long as you're not using POP, you can also keep the read/unread status in-sync.

Comment: if not POP, then which protocol. The exchange settings I use on the phone don't work on desktop outlook.

Comment: Exchange should use Exchange... IMAP for everything else.  Keep in mind, that for exchange the phone is probably using active-sync... but the desktop will be using the native RPC.  I don't think you can turn off desktop-access... but you can turn off the active-sync.  If you're not inside the network with the exchange server... you may have to resort to imap or RPC over https... or some such.

Comment: Does IMAP sync message read information (& folders)? I've never used it before

Comment: Yep.  POP3 is ooooolllddd... and was never designed to keep "status" information.